# If Statements in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a database that allows you to own lizards or snakes. Of course, one person can own many lizards and/or snakes. The "pet" field is a drop down that allows you to pick either a lizard or snake for each pet, but the fees (which has its own field) for buying each one are different. Lizards are $10 and snakes are $15.

Is there a way to set it so that if you pick "lizard" from the drop down, the fee changes to $10, and if you pick "snake", the fee will change to $15. Instead of manually having to type in each fee. Normally I would write an if statement that says

```
if (pet = snake)
 {
   fee = 15
 }
```

or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Use a table.  The problem with using an IF statement is you need to re-write code when you add new animals or change the price, using a table you just add the new animal and cost to the table.

Create a table called `tbl_Pets`.  I've added `PetID` as an `AutoNumber` Primary Key, PetName is indexed to not allow duplicates, `PetCost` has a currency data type.
[image]

Next create a form and add a combo-box to it.
If using the Wizard: Have the combo-box get its values from a table (tbl_Pets) and add all fields to the combo-box and hide the Key Column.

Add a textbox to the form and set its `Control Source` to `=[Combo0].[Column](2)` (if your combo-box is called Combo0.
This will return the value from the third column (first column is index number 0)
[image]

**or**

Add the combo-box with two fields - `PetID` and `PetName`.
Add the text box and give it a `Control Source` of
`=DLookUp('PetCost','tbl_Pets','PetID=' & [Combo0])` - this will look up the cost based on the ID in the hidden column on the combo-box.
[image]

Comment: Suppose adding new pets or prices isn't an issue, would you still recommend this method?

Comment: I would, but I've had nearly two decades experience of people saying 'don't worry, we'll not want to update it' only to change their minds a few weeks/hours later.  But, if you do want to keep it on the form rather than referencing tables you could use `=Switch([pet]='Snake',15,[pet]='Lizard',10)` as the control source for your text box (with your combo box called `pet`)